# LAMMPS installation: lmp_serial executable missing

Tags: lammps

I am beginner in LAMMPS. I downloaded the latest version for Windows and installed it. However, when I check Bin folder, there is no lmp_serial executable file. It's lmp.exe instead. Is this a problem? Thanks

Comment: No, it is not a problem. The executables are usually named according to the OS that you are building the executable on.